# MSSQLLocalDB doesn't work

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I have installed VS2015 Community Edition (italian version) on my PC with Windows 10 x64.
Before installing it, i had usintall previous version of SQL Server and Visual Studio.

Once I started VS2015 and created a project, I realized that localdb was not working. Then I run these commands to check the status.

```
C:\Users\david>sqllocaldb i
MSSQLLocalDB
Projects
ProjectsV12
ProjectsV13

C:\Users\david>sqllocaldb i MSSQLLocalDB
Nome: "MSSQLLocalDB"
Versione: 13.0.1100.286
Nome condiviso:
Proprietario:              DAVIDE-PC\david
Creazione automatica:        Sì
Stato:              arrestato
Ultima ora di inizio: 11/06/2016 00:26:18
Nome pipe istanza:

C:\Users\david>sqllocaldb s MSSQLLocalDB
Avvio dell'istanza del database locale "MSSQLLocalDB" non riuscito a causa del seguente errore:
Errore durante l'avvio dell'istanza del database locale: avvio del processo di SQL Server non riuscito.
```

This is the error in Event Viewer:

```
La chiamata all'API di Windows WaitForMultipleObjects ha restituito il codice di errore: 575. Il messaggio di errore del sistema di Windows è: {Errore di applicazione}
Impossibile avviare correttamente l'applicazione (0x%lx). Fare clic su OK per chiudere l'applicazione.
Rilevato alla riga: 3730.
```

I have tried reinstalling VS2015 but nothing has changed.
Any solutions?

Thanks